# Calculating custom field values for custom child records

Tags: netsuite

I have created a custom transaction body field (custMyCountField") that I am using on custom item fulfillment form.

This body field should simply display the "count" of items that are in a custom subtab of that fulfillment record. (for example a subtab "MyEntryTab) that has a list of child records of name "custRec_myCustomEntrie".)

The child record (myCustomEntries) has its parent set to "Transaction" but I only display to use it on fulfillment transactions.

I have the custMyCountField field set as a calculated field but I do not know what I would put in the formula to have it show this count of child items (count of myCustomEntries on a subtab) of fulfillment record. Or would there be another way that this should be done?

Comment: In researching, it seems like a calculated field may not be the way to go but rather script this field.  However, what I am having issues with is what event to connect to that would catch when a message in the sublist is added or removed while the parent form is in VIEW mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a search and a custom field that references the search.

1. Create search that does a count of the items in the subtab. Make sure to set transaction as an "Available Filter" and make the search public. the Available Filter is what ties the filtered search results to your transaction.
2. Create custom body field to reference the search result. Uncheck the "Store Value" checkbox - you don't want to store the data - you want to reference the saved search instead. Under the Validation and Default tab, choose the saved search from step 1.

No code required.